# Does the set of sets which are elements of every set exist?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, does the following set exist?
$$
A = \{ x \mid \forall y (x \in y) \}
$$
I can see why a set which is an element of every set cannot exist (it would break the **Axiom of Foundation/Regularity**) but then would $A$ be empty or not exist at all? I am aware of the fact that:
$$
B = \{ x \mid \forall y (y \in x) \} = \emptyset
$$
with the universal set not existing in ZF set theory. Is then $A$ empty for the same reason?

Comment: What do you mean by _'a set contained in'_ – is it 'a set being a subset of' or rather 'a set being an element of'...?

Comment: I meant "being an element of", I will edit the post to make that more clear, thanks!

Comment: @CiaPan Incidentally, that's made clear in the body of the question (even pre-edit) by the consistent use of $\in$ instead of $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, $A$ is just the emptyset.

We don't even need to appeal to Foundation to show this: all we need is that the emptyset exists. To be in $A$, you would have to be in every set, so in particular you would have to be in the emptyset - but that's clearly impossible.

---

Similarly, $B$ is just the emptyset *(at least, in ZFC)*: to be in $B$ is to be a universal set, and *(in ZFC)* there aren't any of those.

Note that this is a little more finicky than the analysis of $A$: there are set theories which **do** have a universal set, such as [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations), and in such theories the class $B$ is **not** empty. In all the set theories I know, however, the class $B$ is a set (whether empty or not): in particular, as long as we have $(i)$ Extensionality, $(ii)$ Emptyset, and $(iii)$ Singletons, we're good (if there are no universal sets then $B$ is the empty class, which is a set by $(ii)$; 
 if there is at least one universal set, then there is exactly one universal set by $(i)$ since any two universal sets have the same elements, and so $B$ is the class containing just that universal set, which is a set by $(iii)$), and these are fairly un-controversial axioms.

(OK fine there are some interesting set theories without Extensionality; but *still*, in all the natural examples I'm aware of $B$ is a set.)

---

Really, there's a slight abuse going on here: a priori $A$ and $B$ are just **classes**. What's really going on is that I have the **formulas** $$\alpha(x)\equiv \forall y(x\in y)\quad\mbox{and}\quad \beta(x)\equiv\forall y(y\in x)$$ defining the classes $A$ and $B$ respectively; I prove in ZFC that "each class is empty," that is, that $$\forall x(\neg\alpha(x))\quad\mbox{and}\quad\forall x(\neg\beta(x)).$$

This now lets me prove "There is a set $U$ such that for all $x$ we have $x\in U\iff \alpha(x)$" - namely, take $U=\emptyset$ - and similarly for $\beta$. This is the "under-the-hood" version of proving that an expression in set-builder notation actually defines a set: we show that there is a set which is *co-extensive* with the defining formula of the class. In my opinion, this is an example of a situation where set-builder notation being used at the beginning makes things harder to follow: really, we should be asking (in the case of $A$) "Is there a set $U$ such that for all $x$ we have $x\in U\iff \forall y(x\in y)$?" which clearly separates *formulas/classes* and *sets*.